# How to use nested loops for fetching the data from a rest api in flutter?

Tags: api, dart, flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a order screen where the placed orders and the items that are placed for each order is displayed. I have used a for loop to fetch the orders from the api but in the order json response it also has items parameter inside which there are multiple items. I am not able to figure out how to place another loop in the code to fetch the items list. So please help me with it...
Thank you..

my json response

```
    [
    {
    "id": 1453,
    "total": "407.00",
    "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 34,
            "name": "Aloo Chaat Salad",
            "product_id": 931,
            "quantity": 1,
            "total": "90.00",
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Aloo Jeera",
            "product_id": 1020,
            "quantity": 1,
            "total": "140.00",
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Banana Shake",
            "product_id": 963,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_class": "",
            "total": "140.00",
        }
    ],
  }
]
```

myModel.dart

```
class OrderListModel {
final int id;
final String total;

 Map line_items = {};

  OrderListModel(this.id, this.total, this.line_items);

 }
```

my code for fetching the data

```
 List<OrderListModel> myAllDatas = [];

Future getDatas() async {
String basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
    base64.encode(
        utf8.encode('${GlobalVar.consumerKey}:${GlobalVar.secretKey}'));

var response = await http
    .get("${GlobalVar.url}wp-json/wc/v2/orders?customer=6", headers: {
  'Authorization': basicAuth,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String responseBody = response.body;
  var jsonBody = json.decode(responseBody);
  for (var data in jsonBody) // loop for fetching the orders
  {
    myAllDatas.add(new OrderListModel(data['id'], data['total'], 
data['line_items'])); // how to place a loop so that i can fetch the items 
inside the line_items parameter too?
  }
  setState(() {});
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
}
}
```

when I fetch the items of line_items i just want to fetch their names and seperate them by commas in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for loop like this -

```
for (var data in body) {
    List items = data["line_items"];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      int id = items[i]["id"];
      String name = items[i]["name"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is not working....It shows me the this error---  type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1hWcOb5oxN3L-HJ5vGX1nrfJx2racxkGA     Check this image. It's working for me. Please show the code you added

Comment: instead of using "data in data", use another variable

Comment: I changed the data to dataItems still the problem remains the same...can u please fetch the data from the url and try again if it works?

Comment: What is GlobalVar?

Comment: Move List items = data["line_items"]; outside the for loop, fetch the list first and then run the for loop on it. So, for loop should now be like this - for (var dataItems in items)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5REyRF5m - This is working. It fetches data from the url as well.

Comment: ya thanks i got some lead..but cant we add the name,quantityt and price to the items list and display it using a listView.builder?

Comment: you can. Make a list items_list and save items like items_list[i] = items[i]["id"];. After this you can use listview.builder. Please mark the answer.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aLLP4Spt......Is this the correct way as i am getting the items_list.length as null

Comment: No make a class to save your data, say you name it Item. Declare an empty list of type Item and then when you receive your data, populate it in an instance of type Item. Add this instance to the list using items_list.add(item_obj); I recommend you to read about Lists and ListView.

Comment: I am able to display it in the listview but its showing me repeated items..like each items 3 times...but when i modified the number of times the inner for loop will be repeated to 1(eg. i < 1).can u tell me why?

Comment: How have you declared myAllDatas? You can contact me on keertipurswani27@gmail.com. Should be easier.